# Wordpress Plugin with a shortcode that dynamically generates javascript. Can I use add_action without wrapping the javascript in a function?

Tags: plugin-development, javascript

Looks like the best way is using:

add_action('wp_footer', returnJs);

But if my returnJs function is inside my shortcode function and it's used more than once on a page it will return an error trying to re-create the function.

Is there a way to use add_action and have my js code in a variable instead of wrapped in a function or maybe another way to include it.

It is dynamically generated based on a variable in the short code so the js will be unique for each shortcode.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you add the error you're seeing?

Answer (score 1):

What you need is the [function_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.function-exists.php) method

you would use it like this when defining your `returnJs` function:

```
if( ! function_exists('returnJs') ){
    function returnJs(){
        //Code goes here
    }
}
```

However, better practice would be to just define the `returnJs` function in your plugin